# The Mono.flatMap is not working while mocking the response using MockWebServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor, mockwebserver

Making an HTTP call using WebClient, from the Mono output I want to do some logic, for which I'm using flatMap method.

```
        Mono<Response> authResponseMono = webClient.post().syncBody(requestBody)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class);

        return authResponseMono.flatMap(authResponse -> {
        //code removed for brevity
        });
```

Using OkHttp MockWebServer library to mock the response and unit test the functionalities. The `flatMap` method is not getting invoked while using MockWebServer, however, on the actual calls things are working fine.

Following is the snippet used to mock the HTTP response

```
server.enqueue(mockResponse); //server is instance of MockWebServer
Optional<Response> optionalResponse = authClientService.verifyToken().block(); //verifyToken returns authResponseMono
```

I think the cause for this behavior is due to the way mocks are created internally by the MockWebServer. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I use MockWebServer and webClient and it seems to be fine. Maybe you can post more detail.

here is a snippet of my setup - note this is not a spring test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountDetailsRetrievalTest {

    private static final String ACCOUNT_DETAILS_PATH = "/AccountDetailsPath";
    private MockWebServer server;

    private WebClient webClient;

    private AccountDetailsRetrieval accountDetailsRetrieval;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.server = new MockWebServer();
        this.webClient = WebClient.create(this.server.url(ACCOUNT_DETAILS_PATH).toString());
        accountDetailsRetrieval = new AccountDetailsRetrieval(this.webClient, ACCOUNT_DETAILS_PATH, 300);
    }

    @After
    public void shutdown() throws Exception {
        this.server.shutdown();
    }

@Test
public void nameHasBeenChanged() {
    String content = "{\"bar\":\"bar1\",\"foo\":\"foo1\"}";
    MockResponse response1 = new MockResponse()
            .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .setBody(content);
    this.server.enqueue(response1);

    StepVerifier.create(accountDetailsRetrieval.getAccountData(new AccountDetails("001", "ABC")))
            .assertNext(response -> {
                assertThat(response).isNotNull();
                assertThat(response.getHttpStatus()).isEqualByComparingTo(HttpStatus.OK);
                assertThat(response.data().get("bar")).isEqualTo("bar1");
                assertThat(response.data().get("foo")).isEqualTo("foo1");
            })
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

Response here is just a wrapper for JsonNode